# SQL UPDATE statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I need a little help.  I am trying to set all places where sent=0 to make them all sent=1

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db = "HomeMessages";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username, $password, $db);  
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM notification_queue WHERE sent='0'");


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     //email
     echo 'yes';
     $sql = "UPDATE notification_queue SET sent = '1' WHERE sent ='0'";
} else {
    //don't email
}
?>
```

It echos yes on the page, so I know it is trying to run the sql command.

Here is my database if this helps:

[image: database]

Comment: I don't understand the point of the SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execude your query:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db = "HomeMessages";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username, $password, $db);  
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM notification_queue WHERE sent='0'");


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //email
    echo 'yes';
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE notification_queue SET sent = '1' WHERE sent ='0'");
} else {
    //don't email
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE query never ran because you never called `mysqli_query()`.

More importantly, I agree with Strawberry.  I don't think you need the SELECT query.  You can check the UPDATE result for > 0 rows affected to find out if there were any `sent=0` rows.  Always try to run as few queries as possible.  Also, choose object-oriented or procedural style when using mysqli functions; either one, just choose one.  This is object-oriented:

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db = "HomeMessages";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username, $password, $db);
$mysqli->query("UPDATE notification_queue SET sent=1 WHERE sent=0");
if($mysqli->affected_rows){
    //email
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    //don't email
}
```